# Stuck on join between three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables to join:  Specs, Results, Addendums.  Specs may or may not have Results.  Results may or may not have Addendums.  The catch is Specs may or may not have Addendums without Results in between.  I have been unable to find a join query that will show this data in a way I expect - which would be specs -> results related to these specs -> addendums related to these results & specs -> addendums related to these specs.  Either the Results-Addendums work or the Specs-Addendums work, but I have been unable to get both.  There are no actual primary/foreign key relationships set up in these tables as it is kind of a backwards engineering scenario.

- Addendums will always have related Specs (determined by longspecnum).
- Addendums will sometimes have related Results (determined by longspecnum & resultcode).
- Results will always have related Specs (determined by longspecnum).

I set up a fiddle with a stripped down example.  Basically the missing piece here is that I would want to see the related ID and specnum on the last 3 rows of the query result.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0ecc8/2

```
SELECT [specs].[id], [specs].[specnum], [results].[resultcode], [results].[result], [addendums].[resultcode], [addendums].[resultaddendum]
FROM specs 
LEFT OUTER JOIN results ON specs.specnum = results.specnum 
FULL OUTER JOIN addendums ON specs.specnum = addendums.specnum AND results.resultcode = addendums.resultcode
```

These are the results I get:

`+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| id      | specnum   | resultcode | result   | resultcode | resultaddendum           |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 4648553 | 043020628 | CBm        | 0.2      | (null)     | (null)                   |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 4648553 | 043020628 | CEZ        | SEE NOTE | CEZ        | in ml/min/1.73 sq meters |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 4648553 | 043020628 | CEY        | >60      | CEY        | Ref Rng: GFR estimate    |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 4648553 | 043020628 | CEY        | >60      | CEY        | failure <15              |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 4648554 | 043046806 | HBC        | 13.3     | (null)     | (null)                   |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 4648554 | 043046806 | HEg        | SEE NOTE | HEg        | No slide review          |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 4648555 | 043046815 | HNY        | 1        | (null)     | (null)                   |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 2555123 | 111219672 | CEg        | 117      | (null)     | (null)                   |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 2555124 | 111203082 | (null)     | (null)   | (null)     | (null)                   |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| (null)  | (null)    | (null)     | (null)   | Rij        | VIT D 25                 |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| (null)  | (null)    | (null)     | (null)   | Rir        | 0-17 years               |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| (null)  | (null)    | (null)     | (null)   | Riz        | Optimum Level: 30-80     |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+`

These are the results I want:

`+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| id      | specnum   | resultcode | result   | resultcode | resultaddendum           |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 4648553 | 043020628 | CBm        | 0.2      | (null)     | (null)                   |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 4648553 | 043020628 | CEZ        | SEE NOTE | CEZ        | in ml/min/1.73 sq meters |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 4648553 | 043020628 | CEY        | >60      | CEY        | Ref Rng: GFR estimate    |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 4648553 | 043020628 | CEY        | >60      | CEY        | failure <15              |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 4648554 | 043046806 | HBC        | 13.3     | (null)     | (null)                   |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 4648554 | 043046806 | HEg        | SEE NOTE | HEg        | No slide review          |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 4648555 | 043046815 | HNY        | 1        | (null)     | (null)                   |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 2555123 | 111219672 | CEg        | 117      | (null)     | (null)                   |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 2555124 | 111203082 | (null)     | (null)   | Rij        | VIT D 25                 |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 2555124 | 111203082 | (null)     | (null)   | Rir        | 0-17 years               |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 2555124 | 111203082 | (null)     | (null)   | Riz        | Optimum Level: 30-80     |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+`

Comment: Please [read this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/spaghettidba/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Show us what you *want* to see - as an example.  But I have a feeling that you will not see Specs ID where there is no match between Specs and Addendums entry

Comment: Given your sqlfiddle example data (Thanks for including that!) could you add here your desired results after all this joining. I suspect that a UNION might do what you want, but it's tough to understand your desired results through your description alone.

Comment: From my experimenting it seems like a UNION might be the route I have to go.  It just seemed like there was some magical join combination I was not seeing but maybe not.  Thanks.

Comment: Can/Cannot you give us some of your code?

Comment: What code do you mean?  There's a query in the sql fiddle - I can paste it here if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this possibly right?

```
SELECT        
    [specs].[id],
    [specs].[specnum], 
    coalesce([results].[resultcode], [addendums].[resultcode]) as resultcode, 
    [results].[result],
    [addendums].[resultaddendum]
FROM
    specs LEFT OUTER JOIN
        results FULL OUTER JOIN addendums
            ON      results.specnum = addendums.specnum
                AND results.resultcode = addendums.resultcode
        ON specs.specnum = coalesce(results.specnum, addendums.specnum);
```

There are ways to rewrite that if you don't like that way of specifying the full join first.

Comment: These are the results I get by running shawnt00's query: